# How to force download for remote file in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

My Controller looks like this:

```
public function downloadAction($filename) {
    // Adding url to filename
    $path = $this->container->getParameter('remotepath').$filename;

    // Checking if file exists
    $ch = curl_init($path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($code == 200) {
        // Get the file
        $file = file_get_contents($path);

        // Generate Response
        $response = new Response();

        $d = $response->headers->makeDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT, $filename);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $d);

        $response->setContent($file);
    } else {
        $response = new Response();
        $response->setContent('File not found. ('.$filename.')');
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        $response->setStatusCode(404);
    }
    return $response;
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to get a remote file (image, pdf, ...) and force a download for this file.
But for some reason Symfony is always putting out the header and the file contents as plain text (-> gibberish) in the browser.

I can't find the reason why!

**Edit:**
I altered the code so, that I only create an empty Response() and return it for the controller. On calling the downloadAction with a filename I get the header contents written into the browser window.
So I checked the headers with Firebug and it seems like Symfony responds with normal headers and prints the headers I set to the content. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure file_get_contents returns a file ? As you need the remote server's PHP to have allow_url_fopen set to true it could fail so I would check that first. You might also want to take a look at StreamedResponse, which is better perf wise for this kind of thing.

Comment: See the manual http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#serving-files  They have BinaryFileResponse which might be of interest to you.

Comment: Unfortunately I am working on a Symfony 2.1, which doesnt support the BinaryFileResponse. Sorry for not mentioning the version before. While checking out the StreamedResponse I reached a point, where I fear something is terribly wrong: I altered the code so, that I only create an empty Response() and return it for the controller. On calling the downloadAction with a filename I get the header contents written into the browser window.

Answer (score -3):

This can be done with [RedirectResponse](https://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/RedirectResponse.html) by doing the following in your controller method.

`return new RedirectResponse($yourRemoteDownloadUrl);`

In this example `$yourRemoteDownloadUrl` is a PDF file which is living in a Amazon S3 bucket.

Works in Symfony 2 and 3.

Comment: Fair warning this solution won't "force download" (as asked in the question) a file type that is configured to be served in the browser.  For instance I tried this method to force download PNG files rather than serve them, but they are simply displayed in the browser window.